# If statement problem in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, word-count

My if statement in jQuery seems to be breaking this code and I cannot figure out why:( here is a bit of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function wordCount() //init
{
    $('#text_area').keyup(function () //when you type in the text area
    {
        $('#limit').html($(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length - 1 + ' words'); //count the number of words 
        //and print it out in paragraph #limit 
        //if there are more than 250 words...
        if ($(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length - 1 > 250) {
            //print it out  
            $('#limit').html($(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length - 1 + ' out of 250 words');
            //color it in red
            $('#limit').css("color": "red");
            //disable the submit button.
            $('#submit_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

It works perfectly without an if statement. but as soon as I add some condition, it breaks and displays nothing in #limit.

Thanks

Comment: try alerting `$(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length` are you getting your desired output??

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Instead of calculating the number of words three times, calculate it just once and store it in a variable. Try setting up a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code, and it will be easer for other people to debug.

Comment: yes that's the thing, the $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length bit is perfect, but it breaks with ifs and whiles. and i don't get what i am doing wrong, because it seems correct:/

Comment: @blargie-bla i tried to make jsfiddle of your situation and it working with if you can debug it http://jsfiddle.net/zaknd/

Comment: As an aside, you may not realize this, but in regular expressions the dash - has a special meaning inside character classes. This means that .-: is actually evaluating to ./0123456789: and the dash is not being considered. In order to include dashes as a single item in the class you need to put the dash first or last in the list.

Comment: thank you, i am going to work on it now:)

Comment: and thank you Zimzat, I've already noted that bug too, didn't know how to remove it for the time being, and now I do:) thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `length` that comes out? Have you considered that the reason it "breaks" is that the condition evaluates to `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is breaking when the `if` statement is present because this:

```
$('#limit').css("color": "red");  // semi-colon is wrong
```

should be:

```
$('#limit').css("color", "red");  // use a comma instead
```

---

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/H2JWy/

```
$(document).ready(function wordCount() //init
{
    var limit = $('#limit');
    var submit = $('#submit_button');
    $('#text_area').keyup(function() //when you type in the text area
    {
        var len = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length - 1;
        limit.html(len + ' words');
        if (len > 250) {
            limit.html(len + ' out of 250 words').css("color", "red");
            submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

assign your  `$(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length` to a variable and use that your if

```
var length = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length ; 

 if ( (length- 1) > 250) {


 }
```

@blargie-bla . if you say your `$(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length` is working .

UPDATE

also

```
$('#limit').css("color": "red");
```

should be

```
$('#limit').css("color","red");
```

this should work

Comment: if you read patrick's answer, that will show. Was my silly mistake that I couldn't spot:( but thank you!